# How can I scale notification text based on length?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am making a notification feed where you can view the WHOLE comment a user posts on a blog but I am unable to get the whole multi-line comment to show without affecting the spacing/alignment of elements to match the other notifications.

I was able to make the whole comment show by typing in a constant .frame(height: 100) modifier but then EVERY comment notification has that sized of frame.

Is there a way to make the below VStack scale it's frame dynamically based on the comment length or is there a better way based on my code??

Thank you!

```
struct CommentNotificationCell: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var session: SessionStore

    var activity: CommentActivity?

    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 10) {
            if let activity = activity {

                VStack {
                    KFImage(URL(string: "\(url)" )!)
                    Spacer()
                }
                // Should I scale this VStack's frame height dynamically based
                // on the length of the comment..?
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 3) {
                    HStack(spacing: 3) {
                        Text(activity.username)
                            .font(.caption)
                        Text("commented on your post:")
                            .font(.caption)
                    }
                    Text(activity.comment)
                        .font(.caption)
                    Text(activity.createdAt.timeAgoDisplay())
                        .font(.caption)
                }.padding(.leading, 10)

                Spacer()
                VStack {
                    ZStack {
                        Image(systemName: "bubble.left.fill")
                            .font(.system(size: 13, weight: .regular))
                            .foregroundColor(.blue)
                            .zIndex(1)
                            .offset(x: -25,y: -20)
                        KFImage(URL(string: "\(url)" )!)
                            .zIndex(0)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your code is already doing that – scaling dynamically based on text length. I cleaned it up a little and for me it works. Is there some other place where you set a specific `.frame`?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var test = false
    
    let username = "funnytest"
    let shortComment = "kjfdglkj ewoirewoi oikdjsfgdlsfgj 0ewiropsdisg"
    let longComment = "kjfdglkj ewoirewoi oikdjsfgdlsfgj 0ewiropsdisg poksaf#ldsifsgali oeirpo dgiodfig odfi ofdgifgpoüi fhfdi mfoidgho miohgfm ogifhogif hiogfh fgihi  oogihofgi hofgiho fgopihfgoih pfdgihdfg podfgihofgiho po fdgdfiopugiouü"
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            CommentNotificationCell(username: username, comment: shortComment)
            CommentNotificationCell(username: username, comment: longComment)
        }
    }
}
        
struct CommentNotificationCell: View {
    
    var username: String
    var comment: String
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 10) {
                Image(systemName: "person.circle")
                    .resizable().scaledToFit().frame(width: 60)

            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 3) {
                HStack(spacing: 3) {
                    Text(username)
                        .font(.caption).bold()
                    Text("commented on your post:")
                        .font(.caption)
                }
                Text(comment)
                    .font(.caption)
                Text("8 hours ago")
                    .font(.caption)
            }.padding(.leading, 10)
            
            Spacer()
                ZStack {
                    Image(systemName: "bubble.left.fill")
                        .font(.system(size: 13, weight: .regular))
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                        .zIndex(1)
                        .offset(x: -25,y: -20)
//                    Image("URL(string: "\(url)" )!")
//                        .zIndex(0)
                }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I edited my code to show the full hierarchy, could it be something to do with everything being in a List view?

Comment: When I comment out my Spacer()s then the comment will fully show but then the profile-picture, spacing gets messed up. Weird..

Answer (score 0):

I found out the fix was to remove the Spacer() in the first VStack

```
  VStack {
    KFImage(URL(string: "\(url)" )!)
  }
```